# Difference between Compute.Snapshots.Insert and Compute.Disks.CreateSnapshot for creating snapshots of DISKS?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was working to create the snapshot of persist disk through JAVA.
While I was working on it, I came across two methods,
**Compute.Disks.CreateSnapshot** and **Compute.Snapshots.Insert** , both create a snapshot . What is the difference between them?